# Problemas com musicas em Windows Forms em C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Estou fazendo um trabalho para faculdade com Orientação a Objetos e Windows Forms,porem estou com o seguinte problema:

O programa consiste de varios forms,no primeiro eu fiz o código para tocar musica como mostra o código abaixo

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        som = Path.Combine(CaminhoMusica, "MenuSom.mp3");
        WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer musica = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();
        musica.URL = som;
        musica.controls.play();
        musica.settings.setMode("loop", true);
        guardar.Tocandomusica = true;
    }
```

porem,quando eu abro qualquer outro forms que tenha o evento Load, como por exemplo esse

```
 private void Habitos_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (animal is Cachorro)
        {
            lbAnimal.Text = "Cachorro";
            lbClassificacao.Text = "Mamifero - Predador";
            pnMamiferos.Enabled = true;
            pnPredadores.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
```

ao final da execução do evento load, a musica para de tocar no programa inteiro, e isso é uma coisa que acontece apenas nos forms que tem um evento load, nos outros a musica continua tocando normalmente, o que eu posso fazer para resolver isso?

EDIT:Debugando o código, percebi que o problema não esta no evento load e sim em

```
            Habitos habitos = new Habitos(x.Valor);
            this.Hide();
            habitos.ShowDialog();
            this.Show();
```

na linha habitos.ShowDialog();,porem ainda não sei o que esta causando isso, pois é só em alguns forms especificos.

EDIT2: Resolvi o problema,tive que instanciar o WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer musica = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer(); fora do evento Load do primeiro form, pois me parece que após abrir um certo numero de forms, o load do primeiro era finalizado e assim o objeto musica era deletado junto

Comment: Olá @Renato. Edite a sua questão e coloque o código em texto formatado ao invés de imagem.

Comment: Editei a questao

Comment: O que é WMPLib?

Comment: Não sei explicar técnicamente o que é, mas esse WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer serve para poder reproduzir sons no windows media player via código

Comment: Enfim, ja resolvi o problema, vou editar a questão com a resposta pra caso alguem tenha o mesmo problema